# How to access form property using a dynamically generated property name to fill multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript

I am passing a parameter to a function that is filling dynamically created select (dropdown) boxes.
This works fine when I use the literal string `document.SiteForm.items_list1` within the for loop. However, when I try to access this element using a parameter `(id)` to create the selectbox name (`dynamicSelectboxName`) which is exactly like the `document.SiteForm` string above - it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`. `SiteForm` is the name of my form.

```
function addOption_list(id) {       
    var dynamicSelectboxName = 'items_list' + id;
    var items = new Array(
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3");
    var values = new Array(
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        
        addOption(document.SiteForm.dynamicSelectboxName, items[i], values[i]);
    }
}

function addOption(selectbox, text, value) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}
```

Replacing with this works fine:

```
addOption(document.SiteForm.items_list1, items[i], values[i]);
```

I have also tried replacing `var` with `let` hoping that would somehow work but it doesn't.

Comment: `document.SiteForm.dynamicSelectboxName` is probably undefined. Did you mean to access the property value? `document.SiteForm[dynamicSelectboxName]`

Comment: `document.SiteForm[dynamicSelectboxName]`

Comment: @evolutionxbox That works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad the issue was just a small "typo". do you know why the brackets make a different?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No. Please do explain why brackets are needed here.

Comment: `obj.a` gets the value of the property `a` inside `obj`, `a` is not a variable. This is the same as writing `obj['a']`. Next, `let a = 'whatever'; obj[a]` we are asking for the value of the property `whatever` in `obj`. This is the same as writing `obj['whatever']` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors